# Get "unable to find api field in struct Container" with "kubectl patch" called through Ansible

Tags: ansible, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I'm trying to debug a problem I don't know enough about.  It involves an integration of Ansible, Helm, and Kubectl, all running in a container on a CI server.

We have a Docker image that runs Ansible.  I don't know if it's a custom image or not.  It's called "ansible:2.2", so it seems like it's referring to version 2.2 of Ansible.

We recently made some build changes that integrate Helm.  Instead of storing k8s templates in git, we use Helm to generate the templates, and fill in some additional properties with Ansible.

In two of the services I've upgraded to use the new build system, I see an Ansible error message that starts like this:

> failed: [] (item=/home/aft/ansible/roles/_configrole/tasks/../templates/k8s/deployment_bg.yaml) => {"changed:" true, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/kubectl", ...], ..., "stderr: "error: error when applying patch:\n\nto:...

This is followed by large blocks of json, and finally ending with:

> unable to find api field in struct Container for the json field \"$setElementOrder/env\"

In the overall large error message, seemingly as part of the "kubectl patch" error message, I see three large blocks labeled with "original", "modified", and "current", all of which are slightly different variations of a k8s Deployment object.

I can't figure out the relationship of these three "original", "modified", and "current" blocks to the text of this error message.

In the first service that we saw this error message in, one of the build admins said that he tried deleting the existing Deployment object instead of letting the process try to modify it, and that appeared to work, but I believe that is not ideal.

Comment: Merely for your consideration, ansible 2.2 is **ancient**; the [modern version is 2.9.5](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/releases/tag/v2.9.5). Your question is also at risk of closure for not providing the whole error message, nor a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that could enable anyone to plausibly help you

Comment: There are a lot of similar topics at kubernetes issues on a github. For example this one: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50040 . what's the output of `kubectl version` ?

Comment: I've heard anecdotal evidence that this is all due to an issue in kubectl, having trouble modifying the elements of a list component, due to issues with random map traversal. In this case, I've effectively resolved the problem by first doing a "kubectl delete" of the deployment before running this command. This is safe, as we use "blue-green" deployments, so this deletes the inactive deployment. kubectl client: v1.17.0; server: 1.13.5.

Comment: It is a must to have a kubectl version that is within one minor version difference of your cluster. For example, a v1.13 client should work with v1.12 , v1.13, and v1.14 master. Using the latest version of kubectl helps avoid unforeseen issues. Have you been trying to run the same with kubectl 1.14?  From your comment I can understand that the issue is solved. Am I right?

Comment: It's only "solved" because I hacked around it, by deleting the existing deployment before the rollout attempt, which avoids the issues with modifying list components in existing objects. I had just stated that I'm using client version 1.17 with server version 1.13.15, but I realized that was from my desktop, which is not the same kubectl installation. I added a log statement to our CI builds, which shows we're using client version 1.9.3. That clearly violates your guideline, but can you provide documentation that supports that statement?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#before-you-begin states that it is a must to have a kubectl version that is within one minor version difference of your cluster. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/ states similar things as well

Comment: Acknowledged. That documentation helps. I'll push for this change and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum up the discussion in comments.

The issue has been fixed according to: [.../issues/50040](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50040) and
[.../pull/49834](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/49834).

Additionally, documentation <sup>[[ 1 ]](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#before-you-begin)</sup>  <sup>[[ 2 ]](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/)</sup>  states that:

> You must use a kubectl version that is within one minor version difference of your cluster. For example, a v1.2 client should work with v1.1, v1.2, and v1.3 master. Using the latest version of kubectl helps avoid unforeseen issues.
>
> In highly-available (HA) clusters, the newest and oldest kube-apiserver instances must be within one minor version.
>
> kubelet must not be newer than kube-apiserver, and may be up to two minor versions older.
>
> `kube-controller-manager`, `kube-scheduler`, and `cloud-controller-manager` must not be newer than the kube-apiserver instances they communicate with. They are expected to match the kube-apiserver minor version, but may be up to one minor version older (to allow live upgrades).
>
> kubectl is supported within one minor version (older or newer) of kube-apiserver